# Showing an Administration ActionLink if Users are in an Admin Role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I want to display an Admin ActionLink on my homepage if a user's role is 'Admin'. I have managed to get the roles configured correctly but I'm unsure how to do it.

So far I have implemented the following code into my HomeController:

```
        Function Admin() As ActionResult
        If Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") Then
            Return View("Admin")
        Else
            Return View()
        End If
        End Function
```

I have then implemented the following ActionLink into my Site.Master:

```
<li><%: Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", New With {.Controller = "Home"})%></li>
```

I know this isn't correct but it's not something I've done before so I'm not too sure how it can be implemented correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write this code inside your view using `razor`, something like this:

Razor

```
@If User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", New With {.Controller = "Home"})</li>
End if
```

ASPX

```
<% If User.IsInRole("Admin") Then %>
   <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", New With {.Controller = "Home"})%></li> 
<% End if %>
```

Comment: what is the diff between razor and aspx?

Comment: Look it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569809/mvc-3-aspx-vs-razor-view-engine

Comment: I just had to change 'User.IsInRole' for 'Roles.IsUserInRole'and it worked fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with `VB.NET` But you can do it by writing a custom Helper function as below:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
    {
         return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

so you can use this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin").If(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my ignorance but I have never used custom helpers before. Where do I implement two sections?

Comment: @David As you see, custom helper is nothing but an extension method , so you will need to put it anywhere but in a static class (`HelperExtensions` may be)...and you can use it on any view page by just importing the namespace in which the static class is put...